# Office Web Apps 2010 patches are cumulative?

Tags: office-web-apps, cumulative-update, update, patching

We have SharePoint 2010 farm with Project server 2010 and Office Web Apps 2010 installed. Patched to SP2.

Since OWA 2010 SP2 was released at 2013, we are planning to patch the 27 missing updates from 2013 up to now.

May I know the updates (e.g. [MS16-133: Description of the security update for SharePoint Server 2010 Office Web Apps: November 8, 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3127954)) are cumulative updates? Do I need to patch all 27 updates one by one in release order?

Also, may I know the suggested procedure to update OWA? For SharePoint patch we need to run configuration wizard but do I need for OWA?

Comment: Hi Mark,
The procedure to update OWA is described by Microsoft here: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj966220.aspx. But I found your question looking for the same answer - if OWA patches are really cumulative or not. No answer for now, so I will post the same question for SP2013 OWA and also will do some testing by myself.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have already know an answer, but someone like me could find this useful.
I can confirm that patches for Office Web Apps 2010 and 2013 are cumulative, so you need to install only the most recent one.
Although it doesn't have a title of "cumulative update" itself, when you read KB description page for the patch, you will find a hint like this: "This security update replaces previously released security update" or "For the list of files this cumulative update KBxxxxxxx contains, download the file information"